# How to change rendering flow of slides in Swiper Cover Flow Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Have installed Swiper in my project following

https://idangero.us/swiper/api/#coverflow-effect

I would like to use cover flow effect like in this example:

https://codepen.io/addzycullen/pen/kXKKBZ

I have installed Swiper and added it's CSS, JS CDN to project.

```js
 var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container-aboutus', {
    // Optional parameters
    effect: 'coverflow',
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    initialSlide: 3,
    keyboardControl: true,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    lazyLoading: true,
    preventClicks: false,
    preventClicksPropagation: false,
    lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    coverflow: {
      rotate: 0,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 250,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows : false,
    }
  })
```

```css
.swiper-container-aboutus {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.5.0/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row swiper-container-aboutus">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>

  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**script.js**

Have added this part as jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container-aboutus', {

    effect: 'coverflow',
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    initialSlide: 3,
    keyboardControl: true,
    mousewheelControl: true,
    lazyLoading: true,
    preventClicks: false,
    preventClicksPropagation: false,
    lazyLoadingInPrevNext: true,
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    coverflow: {
      rotate: 0,
      stretch: 0,
      depth: 250,
      modifier: 1,
      slideShadows : false,
    }
  })
});
```

From code snippet you can see that I have achieved cover flow effect but not in wanted way.

I'm not sure what am I missing any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different version of Swiper here: 4.5.0, in codepen example: 3.3.1  - check [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) to find differences.

Comment: After changing version of Swiper works good! Thanks mate! :) Do you know maybe how I can make my `Slide1` to display first? As now it starts from `Slide4`.

Comment: Change "initialSlide" value to 0 instead 3

Comment: Works like charm :) Thanks!